# How to read data, https using 7001 port in a NAS drive with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, network

I have some geograhical data in a Network Attached Storage. How can I read that using QGIS through https protocol by 7001 port ?

Comment: What have you tried?  How do you usually access data from the NAS (ie not through QGIS)?

Comment: web access protrocol     for example : h t t p s ://abcde.efgh.com:7001

Comment: It would be useful to understand why you want to do this, as this might help someone find you a solution.  Also more information about your system would be good (like which NAS)...   Does the NAS only give you the option of internet access over port  7001? Why do you need to use HTTPS protocol to connect to the NAS?  The solution will probably be based on setting up a reverse proxy of some sort, but you haven't provided enough detail to say either whether this is possible, or how it might be best achieved.